# I'm having a problem with my rig. How do I fix the weird scaling of my mesh?

Tags: rigging, bones, transforms

The bones of the armature I created for the arms, legs, body, (ect.) work fine, but the bones I have for the fingers keep scaling the vertex groups when rotating.[image] [image]

This is what happens. It doesn't happen to the other bones, and I don't know how to fix it. I've tried giving the bones different rigify bone types, and I've tried putting more bones in the finger. I've also tried to adjust the position of the bones, but I can't get anything to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have included the vertices of your fingers in another vertex group other than the individual fingers. To fix this, go into edit mode and select your fingers. Then remove those vertices from all other vertex groups. That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the scaling, change the names of the vertex groups (so that the rig doesn't affect those groups) like index.L to Index.L. then add a hook modifier to the mesh. Select the rig as the object, the bone you want to control the vertex group as the bone, and the vertex group you want to control as the vertex group.[image]

Do this for every bone and vertex group pair you need to fix, and that will fix the problem.

Comment: I tried this, and it worked. However, when I moved the wrist bone of my character, it moved the fingers more than they should move.